# Parameters in a Excel Web Query

Tags: excel, web, parameters

I'm trying to import data from the web and it works fine for a static URL.
The URL looks something like this: http://www.foo.com/api/v0.9/csv/items/3/1
The last number (here "1") controls the page count. As there is about 200 pages in total I'd rather not remake 200 static queries, so my question is how can I parametrize this?

I've searched the internet and the only solution I found it changing the URL in something like http://www.foo.com/api/v0.9/json/items/3.html?page=1
But my URL just works differently so the solutions don't apply.

Can anyone tell me how it can be parametrized in my case or point me in the right direction?

Thank you for your time

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want one web query to show 200 pages? All at once? In order? Do you want to do something with the data before it changes from one page to the other? Or do you want to type the page number in a cell and update the web query?

Comment: Yes I want it to just show those 200 pages sequentially. Each page itself doesn't contain much data so it shouldn't be a problem in regard to the amount of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change QueryTable.Connection property to point to a different URL. Here's an example

```
Dim i As Long
Dim qt As QueryTable

For i = 1 To 200
    Set qt = Sheet1.QueryTables(1)
    qt.Connection = "URL;http://www.foo.com/api/v0.9/csv/" & i
    qt.Refresh False


    'Do some stuff with the data
Next i
```